# Scrapy won't call scraper function

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have written a scraper using Scrapy and I have a weird yet simple problem.

I login using u/p to scrape the data but sometimes the site redirects me to /login.asp page with redir= query parameter containing the url I was about to scrape. so I added re_login_if_needed() function and I call it as the first statement of the parse() callback. The idea is to check if response.url has a redirect URL so I can re-login to the site and continue scrapping with parse() as before.

The problem is that somehow re_login_if_needed() function is never executed. Any DEBUG PRINT statement I put in there, is never printed out.

How could that be?

In by class I have:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        self.re_login_if_needed(response)

        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

    def re_login_if_needed(self, response):
        # check if response.url contains redirect code, i.e: "/login.asp?redir="
        # and relogin ...
```

Comment: can you share your implementation of `re_login_if_needed` ?

Comment: can you run `scrapy crawl quotes` and show the output you are getting, since it runs perfectly in my crawler.

Comment: @kiran.koduru right now re_login_if_needed only has this code print("re_login_if_needed here"). Nothing is printed out.